# Is ConcurrentHashMap's computeIfAbsent thread safe, when nested?

Tags: java, concurrency

I am new to using Map's computeIfAbsent method. I did find (per Java docs) that the entire method invocation is performed atomically. I would like to know (rather confirm) if the following code snippet (inside the method) would be executed atomically.

```
     ConcurrentMap<RunMode, Map<LocalDate, Map<Integer, Set<DomainObject>>>> myCache = new ConcurrentHashmap<>();
```

public void addToCache (RunMode runMode, LocalDate bizDate, DomainObject bean) {

```
    Set<DomainObject> domainObjSet = myCache.computeIfAbsent(runMode, runModeMap-> new ConcurrentHashMap<>())                
            .computeIfAbsent(bizDate, bizDateMap-> new ConcurrentHashMap<>())
            .computeIfAbsent(bean.getId(), domainSet-> Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<>()).add(bean));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you mean by atomicity in here.

It is possible that another threads will get a Map from `myCache` which wont see entry for `bizDate`.

If you want to have fully populated Map from `myCache` before any thread will get it then you need to create and populate it inside `myCache.computeIfAbsent`.

Comment: thanks for responding. My primary objective is that all the domain objects (beans) must be added to the map, when multiple threads invoke this method. The bizDate & runMode are mostly constant.